# Correctly closing a websocket

Tags: javascript, websocket

I create a websocket in my app once the user has logged in so as to communicate with the backend. If the user logs out and in again, I create a new websocket object. Should I be calling `close()` on the previous object or is it automatically called during garbage collection - context manager pattern? What should I do if the user suddenly closes there browser window? Should I be explicitly calling `close()` in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to explicitly close the Websocket message if the user closes the Browser, the Browser is doing it for you (or the Websocket will timeout).

It is whise to close the Websocket if you don't need it anymore. The Browser will send Keepalive messages aka Ping/Pong messages to the server. As long the Client responses the Websocket will stay active and consume resources.